# Does Font Awesome icons work in the Google App Engine Environment?

Tags: css, wordpress, google-app-engine

[image]

In screenshot above, I have three social media icons appearing as squareboxes. I checked the following html code.

```
<ul class="nav pull-left">
        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
        <li><a title="Like us on WA Facebook" href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-lg"></i></a></li>
        <li><a title="Follow us on WA Twitter" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg"></i></a></li>
        <li><a title="Subscribe to our WA Youtube channel" href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube fa-lg"></i></a></li>
 </ul>
```

And I confirm its link stylesheet does exists.. I never had this issue on my local machine environment and both of my local wordpress version vs the online wordpress version are exactly the same ie 3.5.1.  So why is it that after uploading to Google App Engine that I get this display problems?

Has anyone encountered this problem when migrating Wordpress into Google App Engine before?

Comment: I believe it's none of GAE's business. What if you inspect the <li> tag in the developer tools. Can you see the style rules of the class "fa"?

Comment: Yes. I can.  No problems.  fa class does exist and I can navigate the font-awesome.css perfectly okay.

Comment: What about path to font file? Is it correct ?

Comment: Yes.  It does. Checked it under Chrome Dev Tools. It's there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I faced a similar problem a few days ago. The problem is mainly with GAE not being able to recognize the mime-type of the font files like .woff, .otf, .ttf and so on. You have to manually set it in your app.yaml file.

This question elaborates on how to do that [Could not guess mimetype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20425364/could-not-guess-mimetype).

But an **easier** method I found was to just add the font-awesome fonts in the head section which is the first method given in this link http://fontawesome.io/get-started/.

That worked for me. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Shashank! I'm glad to know that there's somebody out who's definitely experiencing the same strange problem as I'm getting.  I thought I'm the only who's getting this problem!  Cheers!

Comment: what is the 'first method' on that page??