# Could not guess mimetype

Tags: google-app-engine, go

On the test server `goapp serv` it works, on the appengine itself it get overwritten by application/octet-stream.

How can I tell appengine to stop doing that?

`Could not guess mimetype for home/fonts/FontAwesome.otf. Using application/octet-stream...`

My config file:

```
application: test
version: 0
runtime: go
api_version: go1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
 - url: /home
   static_dir: home

 - url: /home/font/(.*\.woff)
   static_files: home/font/\1
   upload: home/font/(.*\.woff)
   http_headers:
    Content-Type: application/font-woff

 - url: /home/font/(.*\.svg)
   static_files: home/font/\1
   upload: home/font/(.*\.svg)
   http_headers:
    Content-Type: image/svg+xml

 - url: /home/font/(.*\.eot)
   static_files: home/font/\1
   upload: home/font/(.*\.eot)
   http_headers:
    Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-fontobject

 - url: /home/font/(.*\.ttf)
   static_files: home/font/\1
   upload: home/font/(.*\.ttf)
   http_headers:
    Content-Type: application/x-font-ttf

 - url: /home/font/(.*\.otf)
   static_files: home/font/\1
   upload: home/font/(.*\.otf)
   http_headers:
    Content-Type: application/x-font-otf

 - url: /favicon.ico
   static_files: home/favicon.ico
   upload: home/favicon.ico

 - url: /documentation
   static_dir: documentation

 - url: /.*
   script: _go_app

inbound_services:
 - warmup
```

Comment: Your file is in `/home/fonts` while your settings mention only `/home/font`.

Comment: That was also true :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I believe the reason it's working locally is that your system has the required mime type defined for the .otf extension in the /etc/mime.types or equivalent.

AppEngine probably doesn't have that. So you have to give it a hint about the correct MIME type. It looks like you're trying to do but, but you are using "http_headers". Try "mime_type" instead:

```
  - url: /home/font/(.*\.otf)
    static_files: home/font/\1
    upload: home/font/(.*\.otf)
    mime_type: application/x-font-otf
```

I hope that works for you. The documentation is at:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Static_file_handlers

Comment: I tried the above method. Its not working out for me.Still I get "Could not guess mimetype for fonts/FontAwesome.otf"

Answer (score 3):

It's also worth noting that generic rule should go last, like this:

```
handlers:
- url: /static/fonts/(.*\.otf)
  static_files: static/fonts/\1
  upload: static/fonts/(.*\.otf)
  mime_type: application/x-font-otf

- url: /static/fonts/(.*\.ttf)
  static_files: static/fonts/\1
  upload: static/fonts/(.*\.ttf)
  mime_type: application/x-font-ttf

- url: /static
  static_dir: static
```